# operator overloading : getting unidentifiable errors

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class sales_item  
{  
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&,const sales_item&);

public:

    int item;
    sales_item()
    {
        item=2;
    }
    sales_item operator+(sales_item& item1)
    {
        sales_item item2;
        item2.item = item1.item+item;
        return item2;
    }
};



ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, sales_item& item3)  
{

    out<<item3.item;
    return out;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])  
{  
    sales_item item1,item2;
    sales_item item3=(item1+item2);
    cout<<item3;
    return 0;
}
```

in this program i am overloading the + and << operators. but when im trying to replace the line cout << item3 ; with cout << (item1+item2) ; or cout << item1+item2 ;

i am getting the following errors :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, sales_item const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How is it happening?

Comment: How are the errors unknown if you posted them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey the error was because i was referencing the sales item in the function 
ostream& operator<<(ostream &out,sales_item &item3);  when i removed the & it started working fine.. thanks

Comment: But it's (most likely) not doing what you want it to. It's now creating a copy when calling the function. Just as Luchian said, you should have `const &` in both places.

Answer (score 6):

You implemented

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, sales_item& item3)
```

vs

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&,const sales_item&);
//                                    ^
//                        const is missing in definition
```

Comment: i removed the const at both the places. still i got an error. : invalid operands to the binary expression.

Comment: @jithinc don't remove `const` - the signature should be `ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const sales_item& item3)` in both places.